# Self-declared 'DeclareCiteCommand' shall not increase counter of references

Tags: biblatex, custom-bib

I have created a BibLaTeX library, which contains entries in a custom made BibTeX format of all my colleagues. With help of `DeclareCiteCommand`, I have defined several custom 'cite' commands, which I can use in a LaTeX text. This is very helpful because I just need to use my custom made cite commands to automatically obtain, e.g., the telephone number, address, name, affiliation etc. of a colleague without typing all this explicitly into the text.

So far, so good, all works pretty well!

However, I have one issue: whenever I have a text that is a mixture of text, references inserted via `\cite` and my own 'cite' commands, the numbering of the references gets out-of-order (e.g., in section References) by my own 'cite' commands. In fact, whenever I use one of my own 'cite' commands, the reference counter is increased by +1.

**Question:** how can I avoid that the counter is increased by 1?

Here is a **MWE**, with a following output in form of an image. As it can be clearly see, the references start at 1 and continue at 3, because there is the `\citeColleague{Colleague_1}` command between Ref1 and Ref2.

Thanks for some help!

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

% __________________________________________________________ The BibTeX library
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Bib1,
  Title          = {{Self-inhibition of water dissociation on magnesium oxide surfaces}},
  Author         = {Abriou, D. and Jupille, J.},
  Journal        = {Surf. Sci.},
  Year           = {1999},
  Number         = {1-3},
  Pages          = {L527--L532},
  Volume         = {430},
}

@Article{Bib2,
  Title          = {{Aggregation Pathways and Suzuki phase formation in doped Alkali Halides}},
  Author         = {Aceituno, P. and Cuss\'{o}, F. and de Andr\'{e}s, A. and Jaque, F.},
  Journal        = {Solid State Commun.},
  Year           = {1984},
  Pages          = {209},
  Volume         = {49},
}

@Article{Bib3,
  Title          = {{Precipitation of KCI:PbCI$_{\rm 2}$ system: an X-ray study }},
  Author         = {Acharya, B. S.},
  Journal        = {J. Mater. Sci. Lett.},
  Year           = {1985},
  Pages          = {593},
  Volume         = {4},
}

@Colleague{Colleague_1,
  Colleague         = {Frau Musterfrau},
  Degree            = {Dr},
  Type              = {Collaboration},
  Titlework         = {},
  Titlethesis       = {},
  Position          = {Researcher},
  Employer          = {},
  Program           = {},
  Director          = {},
  Codirector        = {},
  Tutor             = {},
  Myrole            = {},
  Street            = {},
  Venueorigin       = {},
  Venueoriginshort  = {},
  Venue             = {A research center},
  Venueshort        = {Name of center},
  Cityorigin        = {},
  Countryorigin     = {},  
  City              = {Town},
  Zipcode           = {},
  Country           = {Europe},
  Date              = {},
  Defencedate       = {},
  Telephone         = {0562259345347946},
  Email             = {email@email.eu },
  Urlcolleague      = {https://www.blabla.eu},
  Note              = {},
  Timestamp         = {}
}
\end{filecontents*}



% ______________________________________________ The declaration of the entries.
\begin{filecontents}{colleague.dbx}
% Declarations used by all new BibLaTeX entry types
% Dates additional
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=datepart]{
  defencedateyear,
  defencedatemonth,
  defencedateday,
}
% Dates
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=date, skipout]{
  defencedate,
}
% Urls
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim]{
  urlcolleague,
}
% Literal (text) fields
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  city,
  cityorigin,
  colleague,
  country,
  countryorigin,
  codirector,
  datestart,
  degree,
  director,
  employer,
  email,
  league,
  lecturer,
  level,
  myrole,
  partners,    
  position,
  program, 
  state,  
  street,  
  telephone,
  titlethesis,
  titlework,
  tutor,
  type,
  venueorigin,
  venueoriginshort,
  venueshort,
  zipcode,
}
% Declarations for BibLaTeX entry type: colleague
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{colleague}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[colleague]{
  colleague,
  degree,
  type,
  titlework, 
  titlethesis,
  position,
  employer,
  program,
  director,
  codirector,
  tutor,
  myrole,
  venueorigin,
  venueoriginshort,
  street,
  venue,
  venueshort,
  cityorigin,
  countryorigin,
  city,
  country,
  zipcode,
  telephone,
  email,
  date,
  defencedate,
  urlcolleague,
  note,
  timestamp,
}
\end{filecontents}

% _____________________________________________________ The standard LaTeX head

\documentclass[english]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[datamodel=colleague,      % The data model
            maxnames=99,              % Maximum number of authors
            dateabbrev=false,         % Do not abbreviate the date
            natbib=true,              % Natbin compatibility
            sorting=none,             % No sorting
            backend=biber]
           {biblatex}        
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%
%              Here it is. What shal I do here that the counter is not
%              modified?
% ____________________________________________________________ The cite command
%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeColleague}
    {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
     \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
     \usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {%
     {%
     \printfield{colleague}%
     \space(\printfield{venueshort}%
             \newunit%
             \printfield{city}%
             \newunit%
             \printfield{country})%
     }%

    }%
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

% Many, many other cite commands would follow here, but for simplicity,
% I leave them all out.


% __________________________ This is just for that all appears on only one page 

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother


% ______________________________________________________________ BEGIN DOCUMENT

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

This is some text that cites first this reference here: \cite{Bib1}. Then, the 
text mentions this person: \citeColleague{Colleague_1}. After, the text cites
\cite{Bib2} and \cite{Bib3}.

\nopagebreak

\printbibliography[nottype=colleague,
                   nottype=project,
                   nottype=event,
                   nottype=researchstay,
                   nottype=contribution,
                   nottype=lecture,
                   title={Bibliography}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You are essentially creating a split bibliography here. Split bibliographies in `numeric` styles almost always benefit from – or even require – the global `defernumbers` option. With

```
\usepackage[datamodel=colleague,      % The data model
            maxnames=99,              % Maximum number of authors
            dateabbrev=false,         % Do not abbreviate the date
            natbib=true,              % Natbib compatibility
            sorting=none,             % No sorting
            backend=biber,
            defernumbers]
           {biblatex}
```

the numbering is as desired.

If you are never going to use the label numbers for the type `@colleague` and all the other new types you defined, you can turn them off with

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[colleague, project, event, researchstay, contribution, lecture]{skiplab}
```

Indeed `skiplab` alone would be enough here, but situations with split bibliography often require `defernumbers`, so I still recommend `defernumbers` even if you use `skiplab`.

---

It would be not trivial to completely ignore certain `\cite`s for sorting purposes with `sorting=none`, because the order is based on the citation requests that are written to the `.bcf`. There is no simple option that could be set when defining `\citeColleague` that would have this effect, lower level hacks would be required (and that hack could not just block writing the cite request to the `.bcf`, that is required for the citation to be processed at all. The request could possibly be delayed...).

---

You may want to make your `\citeColleague` a bit more `biblatex`-y with

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeColleague}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield{colleague}%
   \setunit{\space}%
   \printtext[parens]{%
     \printfield{venueshort}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{city}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{country}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Avoid hard-coded/naked punctuation and spacing like `(` and `)` or `\addspace` without a `\setunit` in bibmacros and cite commands where possible.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot, works out of the box! Greetings. PS: I used 'defernumbers'